# How many different/unique squares are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A square is divided into four equal parts.

[image]

The adjacent parts can't have the same colour, so for example part 1 and 2 can't have the same colour, but part 1 and 3 can have the same colour. How many different/unique squares can you make if you have:
a) two colours
b) four colours
c) ten colours

I believe the answer to a) is two colours. But I was struggling with b) how to tackle this. My approach was:
Part one can take 4 different colours, then part two can only take 3 colours since it can't have the same colour as part one. Part 3 can't take the colour of part 2, but it can take the colour of part 1, so part 3 can have 3 different colours. Part 4 can't have the same colour as part one and part three, but it can have the same colour as part 2, so part 4 can have 2 different colours. So for b), I thought the answer was: 4*3*3*2, but I am not sure if this is correct. Could someone help me with those 3 problems?

Comment: Do you mean different combination?

Comment: The question is how many unique squares you can make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there be $k$ colors.

Break into cases, either (1) and (3) have the same color or they have different colors.

In the case that (1) and (3) have the same color, pick what that is.  Then each of (2) and (4) can be any of the remaining $k-1$ colors.  This gives $k\cdot (k-1)^2$ options.

In the other case, choose the color of (1) and the color for (3).  Now, each of (2) and (4) can be any of the remaining $k-2$ colors.  This gives $k\cdot (k-1)\cdot (k-2)^2$ options.

This gives the combined total of:

$$k(k-1)^2+k(k-1)(k-2)^2$$

Comment: Could you tell me what's wrong with my method? I did 4*3*3*2 which results in a different answer.

Comment: @Stallmp in order to apply rule of product correctly, the *number* of options at a step must not depend on choices made in previous steps (*though the options themselves may change*).  In your attempt, you claimed that there are only two options available for region (4), however in the event that (1) and (3) were the same color, there are in fact $3$ options available, not two.  There are *at least* two options available for (4), but depending on exact choices made in previous steps there could have been three options available instead.

Comment: If it is difficult for you to see this, consider applying your logic to the case of two colors.  We pick what color region (1) is and have two options for this.  We continue to region (2) where we have only one option available.  We continue to region (3) where we have one option available.  Now, region (4) can not be the same as region (1) and it also cannot be the same as region (3), so did we have $2\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 0=0$ total outcomes?  Certainly not.  I'm sure you can come up with at least one valid coloring.